# clr.dll, version: 4.6.1590.0 crashes the application

Tags: c#, .net

The application was working fine in .Net framework 4.5.1 after upgrading to 4.6.2 clr.dll crashes

---

**The snapshot on event log is**

> Faulting application name: app.exe, version: 8.4.0.1, time stamp: 0x581c401e
>
> Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.6.1590.0, time stamp: 0x5787ee4f
>
> Exception code: 0xc0000005
>
> Fault offset: 0x00017925
>
> Faulting process id: 0xc60
>
> Faulting application start time: 0x01d249797d35fda5
>
> Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Path\app.exe
>
> Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
>
> Report Id: 97a5d5e4-b56d-11e6-80b9-a0d3c1473d5c
>
> Faulting package full name:
>
> Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: An issue nobody can reproduce should be closed or deleted.